# Django absolute url not working in html template

Tags: python-3.x, url, django-views, breadcrumbs, django-2.1

Before I post this question, I tried several solutions, but no vien, maybe because I have little experience in django and web development. 
I want to show the name of a course in a breadcrum navigation menu. However, it shows empty spaces. Using Django 2.1.4, the Model is as follows:

```
class Course(model.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(default='No description available.')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('course-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

## Edit: adding lesson model

The lesson model has many to many relations with course. It is as follows:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

The views.py contains the following views

```
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'courses/courses.html'
    context_object_name = 'courses'
    paginate_by = 10


class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'courses/course-detail.html'

class LessonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'courses/lesson-details.html'
```

The urlpatterns include the following:

```
path('', CourseListView.as_view(), name = 'course-list'),

path('course/<int:pk>/', CourseDetailView.as_view(), name = 'course-detail'),

path('lesson/<int:pk>/', LessonDetailView.as_view(), name = 'lesson-detail'),
```

In the html template of the `lesson-detail`, the following breadcrum nivegation is included:

```
<!-- ##### Breadcumb Area Start ##### -->
<div class="breadcumb-area">
    <!-- Breadcumb -->
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'course-list' %}">Courses</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}">{{course.title}}</a></li> {% comment%} This doesn't work {%endcomment%}
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{ lesson.title }}</li>
            <li></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</div>
```

How can I make it work? The course title is "music", the desired output looks like `HOME / COURSES / MUSIC / FLUTE`.  I want to be able to include the url of the course in several places in the website, including running text.

Your kind help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LessonDetailView` not having any superpower, it cannot guess you want to have a `Course` instance in your template context nor which exact one you want. As a result, the template cannot resolve the name `course` and spits out an empty string indeed.

The good news is that - assuming your `Lesson` model (which you forgot to post) has a ForeignKey on `Course` ie:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, ....)
    # etc
```

then you can get the related course instance from the `lesson` instance, ie:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
  {% with course=lesson.course %}
  <a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}">{{course.title}}</a></li>
  {% endwith %}
</li>
```

EDIT:

> May be because the model has many to many relations and it requires a different solution

Well yes indeed. And before going into any implementation detail, just ask yourself how you can know which of the related courses should be selected if you only have the lesson id ? Answer: you can't. IOW, you have to make the course id part of the url pattern for the lession view:

```
path('lesson/<int:course_id>/<int:pk>/', LessonDetailView.as_view(), name = 'lesson-detail'),
```

then update your view so it gets the course id, retrieve the course from the db and [inject it in the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) (nb: untested code so it might not work out of the box - but you have a very comprehensive documentation to help you):

```
class LessonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'courses/lesson-details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        course = self.object.courses.get(pk=kwargs["course_id"])
        context["course"] = course
        return context
```

And of course reset your template to it's initial version.

EDIT 2:

I forgot to had that this will break `Lesson.get_absolute_url()`, since you depend on knowing the current course, which is not possible in this context. The solution is quite simply to remove this method from the `Lesson` model (actually a Model shiouldn't know anything about urls) and replace all calls to `lesson.get_absolute_url()` by either a call to `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` (in python code) or it's sibling the `{% url %}` templatetag (in templates).

Comment: desthuillier, Thank you for your kind help. I tried what you suggested, but it is still showing empty spaces. May be because the model has many to many relations and it requires a different solution. Please extend your kind help.

Comment: @Mohammed that's why you're supposed to post relevant code in your question - this avoids wasting everyone's time...

Comment: I am really sorry. I apologize for that. Meanwhile I appreciate your valuable time and help.

Comment: Just make sure you post all the relevant context in your question next time... So, I edited my answer according to your real model - but as mentionned, this is untested code and may not work as is (but it should get you started and that's the point).

Comment: Thank you @bruno_desthuilliers for you kind help. I am immensely grateful to you. I implemented the second solution and I found reverse errors. The last thing I want to face is a reverse error (I am new to django!). However, I had to amend the model from ManyToMany to one to many using a foreign key. I tried your first answer and It worked like magic. Thank you for the time you spent helping me out. You are really a savior. Thank you soooooooooooooooo much.

Comment: Err... The problem with reverse errors is trivial to fix (cf my edited answer), and really changing your relationships cardinalities is NOT the proper solution - if the specs says it's a many to many relationship you certainly DONT want to make it a one to many, as it's a totally different thing.

Comment: Also if you really want to show your gratitude please try to really understand how those things work so you can solve your problem by yourself (and eventually help others) instead of relying on others help and/or, even worse,  "copy-paste programming" (which definitly is a garanteed way to fail a project).